# How to find story quests?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I think I might have missed obtaining a story quests that is important. I am about lvl 20 and I have searched all the cities and i have no quests currently in my journal.

How can I find it the story quest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the next story quest in the chain can usually be picked up from the same NPC that you turned in the previous quest to immediately prior. There are a few exceptions, of course, and sometimes there are additional story quests that are picked up from other nearby NPCs (usually in the same room as the main NPC). If you do manage to lose track of where you are, though, there's a pretty simple way to do figure out what sort of quests are available to you in your current area: the Duty Recommendations list.

You can access the recommendations list through your micro menu's Duty icon; it's third from the left on the bottom row.

[image: Accessing the Duty Recommendations list]

[image: Accessing the Duty Recommendations list]

Selecting "Recommendations" will open the list:

[image: Duty Recommendations list]

In this example there are no story quests shown, but if there any quests in your current zone that you haven't picked up yet, they'll show up on this list. This list will also show you available sidequests, quest objectives, dungeons within your level range, levemetes, and other content that's appropriate for your level in your current zone. Clicking any item in the list will show you on your map where you can find that particular thing and/or open the Duty Finder window.

If you don't see any story quests in your current zone, try traveling to another zone that you've been doing stuff in lately (or zones that the story has you visiting often) and check the list to see if there's a story quest that you didn't know about. If you remember roughly where and when your last story quest took place, you could look it up in [the official database](http://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/playguide/db/quest/?category2=1), but beware of spoilers, obviously.

It's possible to make this list pop up every time you log into the game, and/or when you change zones via Character Configuration -> UI Settings -> Duty Recommendations.

[image: Duty Recommendations options]

Comment: Thank you, i finally found the damn thing just by going to the all 3 cities again and using recommended quests!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @cloudymusic's excellent answer, if you look in your quest journal (<kbd>j</kbd>) you can filter on main story quests and read the text for the last one you completed.  There are often hints there as to where to go next.

Answer (score 2):

First, you could try gaining a level or some through non-story quests and FATEs to see if more quests open up for you based on your level. I know that there are quests of a much higher level than 20 so they don't end there.

If you're sure you've missed a quest, you'll have to start searching.

The brute force approach is to go through every city and every region, thoroughly searching, talking to everybody in order to find any missing quests. You should start with the higher level areas, looking especially for places you've never been to, and then move on to lower-level areas. This would be time consuming and not that fun. If you're sure you didn't miss anything in the cities, you could skip re-searching those for now. To make the trip productive, level your other classes while you're at it and swap back to your main when doing interactions.

A simpler approach given that there's no way for us to know exactly which quest you've missed, even if we have a hunch is to [search for a guide](https://www.google.ca/search?q=final+fantasy+14+story+quest+guide). Pick a guide, such as [this one at gamerscape](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Category:Main_Scenario_Quest) and go through the list, looking for any quest(s) you may have missed. Checking through a list of 100-200 quests would take less time than searching every nook and cranny.

If you've done every quest in every guide you can find, then you are really left with only a brute force approach.